# edit functionality is not working in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I just created an editable using an example available on net.in this when i am trying to edit the grid then it doesn't show the value it shows the input field blank.can any body help ?
in edit i am calling this function

```
  self.editFruit = function (fruit) {
        if (self.editingItem() == null) {
            // start the transaction
            fruit.beginEdit(self.editTransaction);

            // shows the edit fields
            self.editingItem(fruit);
        }
    };
```

here is fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/b5q1xp0e/)

Answer (score 2):

At the time the binding is evaluated for the first time the editValue child observable of each of fruit's observables ( `data-bind="value: name.editValue"` ) doesn't exist.  When you click on the "edit" link the editValue observable is created but knockout doesn't know that it has to rebind.

You can solve this 2 ways.

1 . Create a virtual `if` binding around each input.  When the if becomes true, the content will be reinserted back into the DOM causing the bindings to re-evaluate.  Make sure that editValue observable is attached to its parent BEFORE editingItem observable is set, otherwise you are in the same situation

```
<!-- ko if: $root.isItemEditing($data) -->
<input data-bind="..."></input>
<!-- /ko -->
```

2 . Make sure that all observables have the editValue observable attached to the parent observable before the model is bound, the set editValue observable's value in the beginEdit fn.

```
function Fruit(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
  self.name.editValue = ko.observable();

  self.rate = ko.observable(data.rate || "");
  self.rate.editValue = ko.observable();
}

ko.observable.fn.beginEdit = function (transaction) {
  ...

  if (self.slice)
    self.editValue(self.slice());
  else
    self.editValue(self());

  ...
}
```