# KnockoutJS: working example for editable grid

Tags: knockout.js, datagrid

I need a grid which allows switching between editation and viewing. After editing is finished the user can choose whether he wants apply or cancel his changes done on the edited row. Here is an example, which does exactly, what I need: http://jsfiddle.net/peterf/8FMPc/light/

But unfortunately this JSFiddle doesn't work with KnockoutJS v. 3.2.0:
http://jsfiddle.net/8FMPc/315/
When I click on the Edit button, the input doesn't have value (fruits name).
It seems like a problem with data-binding in:

```
<input type="text" class="edit" data-bind="value: name.editValue, visible: $root.isItemEditing($data)"  />
```

Does anyone know, how to solve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7RDc3/) from the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. Unfortunately I need more advanced functionality (I have updated my post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split the state-stuff you're adding using ko.extenders... the problem is that the editvalue observable doesn't initialize until you click the edit button so it doesn't work the first time you click it, but does work after that.

In theory, everything you're trying to do should be done entirely with extenders rather than adding functions like this. If you just want to add functions through the fn ability, they should be entirely stateless in my opinion.

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/zfxmac7z/

**JS:**

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Observable Extention for Editing
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
ko.extenders.editable = function(target, option) {
    if (Array.isArray(target()))
        target.editValue = ko.observableArray(target().slice());
    else
        target.editValue = ko.observable(target());    
};

ko.observable.fn.beginEdit = function (transaction) {

    var self = this;
    var commitSubscription, 
        rollbackSubscription;

    self.dispose = function () {        
        // kill this subscriptions
        commitSubscription.dispose();
        rollbackSubscription.dispose(); 
    };

    self.commit = function () {
        // update the actual value with the edit value
        self(self.editValue());

        // dispose the subscriptions
        self.dispose();
    };

    self.rollback = function () {
        // rollback the edit value
        self.editValue(self());

        // dispose the subscriptions
        self.dispose();
    };

    //  subscribe to the transation commit and reject calls
    commitSubscription = transaction.subscribe(self.commit,
                                               self,
                                               "commit");

    rollbackSubscription = transaction.subscribe(self.rollback,
                                                 self,
                                                 "rollback");

    return self;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Item Model
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function Fruit( name, colour) {
    var self = this;
    // extend to add the editable capability
    // this allows them to initialize right out of the gate
    self.name = ko.observable(name).extend({ editable: true });
    self.colour = ko.observable(colour).extend({ editable: true });
};

Fruit.prototype.beginEdit = function(transaction) {
    this.name.beginEdit(transaction);
    this.colour.beginEdit(transaction);
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* View Model
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function FruitColourViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //  data
    self.availableColours = [];
    self.fruits = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.editingItem = ko.observable();

    //  create the transaction for commit and reject
    self.editTransaction = new ko.subscribable();

    //  helpers
    self.isItemEditing = function(fruit) {
        return fruit == self.editingItem();
    };

    //  behaviour
    self.addFruit = function () {
        var fruit = new Fruit("New fruit", self.availableColours[0]);
        self.fruits.push(fruit);

        //  begin editing the new item straight away
        self.editFruit(fruit);
    };

    self.removeFruit = function (fruit) {
        if (self.editingItem() == null) {
            var answer = true; // confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this fruit? ' + fruit.name());
            if (answer) {
                self.fruits.remove(fruit)
            }
        }
    };

    self.editFruit = function (fruit) {
        if (self.editingItem() == null) {
            // start the transaction
            fruit.beginEdit(self.editTransaction);

            // shows the edit fields
            self.editingItem(fruit);
        }
    };

    self.applyFruit = function (fruit) {
        //  commit the edit transaction
        self.editTransaction.notifySubscribers(null, "commit");

        //  hides the edit fields
        self.editingItem(null);
    };

    self.cancelEdit = function (fruit) {
        //  reject the edit transaction
        self.editTransaction.notifySubscribers(null, "rollback");

        //  hides the edit fields
        self.editingItem(null);
    };

}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* KO Page Binding                                                      */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/   
$(document).ready(function() {

    //  create the model
    var model = new FruitColourViewModel();
    model.availableColours = ["Blue", "Green", "Orange", "Red", "Yellow"];

    var initData = [
        new Fruit( "Apple", "Green"),
        new Fruit( "Banana", "Yellow"),
        new Fruit( "Orange", "Orange"),
        new Fruit( "Strawberry", "Red")
    ];

    model.fruits(initData);

    //  bind model to the html
    ko.applyBindings( model );   

});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your time, Brett! :) I am a newbie in KO and it helped me a lot. I am going to look at the extenders in more detail.

Comment: No problem... in the future, include your code directly in the post. It's OK to have a fiddle, but these can go stale (link rot) and then the question is no longer useful to future visitors. I usually do both inline code AND a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is already answered, but this fruit example was also mine pain. I came out with this:

```
 <!-- ko if: $root.isItemEditing($data) -->
            <input type="text" class="edit" data-bind="value: name.editValue, visible: $root.isItemEditing($data)"/>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

In the older version of knockout model was rebinded more often, thats why it was working before. In newer version:

> At the time the binding is evaluated for the first time the editValue
>   child observable of each of fruit's observables ( data-bind="value:
>   name.editValue" ) doesn't exist. When you click on the "edit" link the
>   editValue observable is created but knockout doesn't know that it has
>   to rebind.

[suggested answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620652/edit-functionality-is-not-working-in-knockout-js)

This will also work for version less than 3.0